# ANTLR ambiguity between hex and opcodes

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, antlr4, lexical-analysis

I'm writing a simple combined lexer/parser for a basic assembly language. My problem is this, when parsing an opcode, I need to parse some hex which is the instruction counter, could be an immediate value, etc, as well as the actual opcode.

Basically, when parsing something like `add` there are a few possibilities, I can have a basic `add` or an add with a condition code `addeq`. The trouble here is that add is also a valid sequence of hex, so I get a lexer error saying `line 1:4 token recognition error at: 'q'`. Of course, if I comment out the `HEX` rules, and ignore the fact that I need to parse the offset, the error disappears; which is how I found the source of the error.

An example line looks something like this: `0000b3ec addeq`. As you can see, it's greedily parsing it as hex, instead of matching the `add` token, and then the `eq` token.

I'm wondering how I can go about switching contexts such that in this case I can ignore the possibility of hex occurring in this sequence. I am not excited about separating my lexer/grammar, but I can if absolutely needed. `pushMode` and `popMode` seem to be in the right direction, or somehow a non-greedy rule, but I'm at a bit of a loss.  I'd really appreciate any insight on this or this class of problems in general because the context of the match seems very appropriate to lexing and parsing properly.

I'm using Antlr4.

```
    grammar failadd;
    opcode      : add cond_code?
                ;
    cond_code   : COND_CODE;
    add         : ADDS | ADD;

    ADD         : 'add';
    ADDS        : 'adds';

    COND_CODE   : CC_EQ;
    CC_EQ       : 'eq'; 
    HEX32       : SINGLEHEX SINGLEHEX SINGLEHEX SINGLEHEX SINGLEHEX SINGLEHEX SINGLEHEX SINGLEHEX;
    HEX16       : SINGLEHEX SINGLEHEX SINGLEHEX SINGLEHEX;
    SINGLEHEX   : [a-fA-F0-9];
    WS          : [ \n\t\r]+ -> skip;
```

Comment: Is it intentional that your grammar parses `addeq` and `add eq` the same way?

Comment: No, I'd like for add to be parsed and then eq such that I can store all `add`s as a single opcode and have a separate field which specifies the condition code (`eq`)

Comment: I was just trying to say that, by skipping `WS`, and parsing `add` and `eq` separately, you allow whitespace in between, which is probably not what you want. You can either live with that, or fix it. I can imagine that a fix would switch to a different mode after `add`, where a condition code could follow, and a whitespace switches back to the initial mode, so that condition codes can't follow a whitespace.

Comment: How do you define a line? I'm not sure I agree with your analysis. It seems to me, the parser matches 'add' as an add command, as an opcode. And then tries to match the remaining 'eq' which can only start as an HEX32, except 'q' is not in set, hence the error. In that case, you could save your problens with a new `ADDEQ      : 'addeq';`

Comment: As @SillyFreak also said, the lack of whitespace confuses me. Can you give a few sample valid inputs you'd like to parse?

Comment: Sure.  `0000b658    e08f1001    add` `0000b698    e08f0000    addeq`. These would have registers after them, I'm just simplifying for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I solved my problem and I'll post the full example so people can learn from what I did. I had to make a separate lexer and grammar in order to switch modes. Also, I promote all similar tokens of the same type to a universal token name which can be used in the parser grammar. By pushing and poping modes, I can set the appropriate token type. Thanks for all of your suggestions, it led me to this relatively clean answer!

The lexer:

```
    lexer grammar testLexer;

    tokens {WHITE_SPACE, TOKEN_OPCODE, TOKEN_ADDRESS, TOKEN_ENCODING, TOKEN_CONDITION_CODE}

    ADDRESS         : [a-fA-F0-9]+ -> type(TOKEN_ADDRESS);
    WS              : [ \t]+ -> type(WHITE_SPACE), skip, pushMode(ENCODE);
    NEWLINE         : [\r\n]+ -> type(WHITE_SPACE), skip;

    mode ENCODE; 
    ENCODING        : [a-fA-F0-9]+ -> type(TOKEN_ENCODING);
    ENC_WS          : [ \t]+ -> type(WHITE_SPACE), skip, popMode, pushMode(OPCODES);

    mode OPCODES;
    OP_WS       : [ \t]+ -> type(WHITE_SPACE), popMode;
    ALL_ADD     : (ADD | ADDS) -> popMode, pushMode(CONDITION_CODES), type(TOKEN_OPCODE) ;
    ADD         : 'add';
    ADDS        : 'adds';

    mode CONDITION_CODES;
    CONDITION_CODE   : 'eq' -> type(TOKEN_CONDITION_CODE);
    WS_COND          : [ \t]+ -> type(WHITE_SPACE), skip, popMode;
```

The parser:

```
    parser grammar testParser;
    options { tokenVocab=testLexer; }

    line    : address encoding opcode condition_code?;
    address : ADDRESS;
    encoding: TOKEN_ENCODING;
    opcode  : TOKEN_OPCODE;
    condition_code : TOKEN_CONDITION_CODE;
```

EDIT: Added the graphical output. [image: Parser tree]

Answer (score 2):

One way to handle this would be to use some lookahead in the way that you define hex tokens.

Note:  the following is not the solution ... but a pointer to the solution.

---

If ANTLR used Perl/Java/Javascript/etc style regexes to specify lexical tokens then you could define the 'hex' tokens something like this:

`[a-fA-F0-9]+($=[^a-zA-Z0-9])`

i.e. hex digits followed by a zero-width lookahead for a non-alpha, non-numeric. Change the `+` to a more constrained repetition if you really need different 'sizes' of hex number in your grammar.

Note that the lookahead must exclude hex characters as well as other alphabetics, or else you could end up with "addeq" analysed as `HEX16("adde") Identifier("q")`.

---

After some further research, I realised that ANTLR is using a simpler, more pure kind of regex that doesn't support that lookahead syntax.  However, I think you should still be able to implement lookahead, using syntactic actions implemented in Java.  See the references for ideas, particularly the 2nd one.

References:

- [Lexical Analysis with ANTLR](http://sds.sourceforge.net/src/antlr/doc/lexer.html)
- [Lookahead predicates in the Lexer?](http://antlr.1301665.n2.nabble.com/Lookahead-predicates-in-the-Lexer-td7579180.html)

Comment: How can I do this in ANTLR4? It's saying that the `$~` came as a complete surprise when I try to define that in a lexer rule.

Comment: @SillyFreak - he's right.  ANTLR doesn't support that syntax

Answer (score 1):

You're almost right with your analysis. Your grammar is not parsing `add` as hex, but `adde`. Since this is four digits, it matches your `HEX16` rule.

Unless you can guarantee that a valid four or eight digit hex sequence will never be a valid opcode, I'm not certain you can do this on the lexer level. You're talking about switching contexts once you parsed the hex, but that won't work in cases when there is no hex.

I would instead do this work on the parser level. You'll need to define a `HEX_OR_OPCODE` token, then in the parser you can use structural information to determine whether to interpret a token as the former or latter:

```
line: hex? opcode;
hex: HEX_OR_OPCODE;
opcode: HEX_OR_OPCODE;
```

In your `0000b3ec addeq` case, `0000b3ec` would be parsed with `hex` and `addeq` with `opcode`. In your visitor, you can handle them appropriately.

As a note, I think this is similar to the common identifier vs. keyword problem, and solutions to that problem may also apply.

Comment: However, I really need to be able to differentiate between the add and the eq as well. Having it parse out addeq, just means I have to add post parsing logic to my program to resolve in ambiguity and I'd rather do it in ANTLR if possible.

Comment: then I would suggest Stephen's way. As long as you don't have opcodes that exactly match hex markers, you should be fine.